# How photons and electromagnetic waves both make light ? Is there any connection between both of them?

Tags: photons

I have seen many videos and websites regarding light, about photons and electromagnetic waves. Somewhere it is said that-

"Light is made of photons, which have wave-particle duality and they carry energy"

And somewhere that-

"Light is an electromagnetic wave, a disturbance in electric and magnetic field which carries energy"

How these two explanations are related and is there any significance of there relation? Please explain.

Comment: A photon is the simplest possible excitation of the electromagnetic field. Its shape will look like a classical wave if you have enough of them.

Comment: The electromagnetic field is made up of billions individual photons.

Comment: Ohh. So its just falls into the Quantum Field Theory box I guess